# UISwipeGestureRecognizer inside UIScrollView does not swipe right - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I am using two swipe gestures inside scrollview so i could be able to change photos and zoom in , swiping left works normally and smoothly while swiping right does not work properly , after many swipes it could be triggered once maybe,i am using this code:

```
//image zoom
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;
    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1280, 960);
    self.scrollView.delegate=self;
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft:)];
    swipeleft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swiperight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiperight:)];
    swiperight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperight];
```

And these two methods to handle the swipe

```
-(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"LEFTtttttt");
    if(index > 0 && index < _photoCount){
        index = index - 1;
        [self loadImage];
    }

}

-(void)swiperight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
       NSLog(@"RIGHTttttt");
    if(index >= 0 && index < _photoCount - 1){
        index = index + 1;
        [self loadImage];
    }
}
```

I searched for a solution of course and tried different codes but it did not work , i added

```
[self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swiperight];
```

And this one too,

```
-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.zoomScale!=1.0) {
        // Zooming, enable scrolling
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
    } else {
        // Not zoomed, disable scrolling so gestures get used instead
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;
    }
}
```

The only difference is when i added the latter code swiping right worked normally when i zoomed in when it should work in the opposite case.

Did i miss something in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please add swipe gesture to the scrollView not on self.view to make it works good when user swipe on scrollView. like below

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft:)];
swipeleft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swiperight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiperight:)];
swiperight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:swiperight];
```

this might be happening because scroll view is rendering above self.view.

Comment: if you still have problem share i will help with you

Comment: Forgot to add, i tried this solution and it did no work.

Comment: @yasserh what exact problem you are facing now? please share,

Comment: Same issue, can swipe left but cannot swipe right unless i zoom in.

Comment: can you try after adding this line     [swipeRight requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];

Comment: @yasserh and add this method in your code, and return bool value as per your need, - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer; and return Yes for allow simultaneous detection of gesture

Comment: Added both methods but it's not working, thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're adding the swipe gesture recognizer to some element other than the scroll view itself, you might need to tick the "User Interaction Enabled" setting